# Wordpress - shortcode for external permalink

Tags: wordpress, external, permalinks, shortcode

Hi folks maybe someone can help me. It does not work and I've already tried everything

This should be the shortcode:

```
[permalink url="http://www.domain.com/" linktext="My Link Text"]
```

And that the associated function:

```
function external_permalink( $atts ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'linktext' => '',
  ), $atts, 'permalink' );

   $url = get_permalink( array(
     'url' => '',
     'target' => 'self'
  ), $url, 'url' );

  return '<a href="' . $url['url'] . '">' . $atts['linktext'] . '</a>'; }
add_shortcode('permalink', 'external_permalink');
```

Comment: You've got to expand on what your question is, as it's very vague.. if it's even there at all. What's your expected output, and what are you getting? Have you debugged? You can't just say 'it does not work'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you even have `get_permalink` because it shouldn't be there. This should work

```
function external_permalink($atts)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'linktext' => '',
        'url' => ''
            ), $atts);

    return '<a href="' . $atts['linktext'] . '" rel="nofollow">' . $atts['linktext'] . '</a>';
}

add_shortcode('permalink', 'external_permalink');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lee - Sorry, I thought it would be understandable what I mean.

@Kirk Beard - Maybe, but I like that better: `[permalink url="http://www.domain.com/" linktext="My Link Text"]`

as this: `<div class="class1 class2"><a href="http://www.domain.com/" target="_blank">My Link Text</a></div>`

@Igor Yavych - Wonderful! It is working. Many many thanks :)